# Can you document the memberwise initializer for a Swift struct, without redefining it manually?

Tags: swift, struct, documentation

Say I have a struct in Swift:

```
struct MyStruct {
    let myInt: Int
    let myString: String
}
```

I get a memberwise initializer for this struct by default

```
MyStruct(myInt: Int, myString: String)
```

But, even if I document this struct and its properties, I won't get any documentation for this memberwise initializer.

[image]

Without having to redefine it manually with the documentation added, does anyone know if it's possible to add documentation for this initializer?

Comment: I believe impossible without redefinition.

Comment: There's a lot of (known) shortfalls to the current state of member-wise initializer, but I don't think this is one of them. If your member-wise initializer needs documentation, I don't think having a member-wise initializer at all is appropriate.